# How to display to screen a detailed report using beyond compare 3 with script?

Tags: beyondcompare, file-comparison, beyondcompare3

I would like to display a detailed report to screen (not saving to output file)

after using beyond compare 3 with script.

Has anyone have an idea how to do achieve such behavior?

Your help is welcomed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond Compare scripts can't output to the screen. You'll have to output the report to a file, then load the file in another application (web browser, Notepad) to display it.

If you want an interactive comparison, you can provide files or folders to compare as command line arguments.

Examples:

```
bcompare.exe c:\file1.txt c:\file2.txt
bcompare.exe c:\folder1 c:\folder2
```